# See raw code/text from copy paste

Tags: copy, clipboard, copy-paste, paste

I doing some formatting from copy/paste. When I copy a table from Word, and I want to insert it in my program, I need to edit the table formatting to show the info like I want.

When I copy from word I can view whats copy in clipboard magic:

[image]

Is there a way to get the formatting, or do I need to create a new table for scratch with the data listed in clipboard magic?

I Clipdiary the "copy" is read as HTML

[image]

This makes me wounder, is it possible to get the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the HTML is present as CF_HTML.  See reference on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917(v=vs.85).aspx

If you just want to SEE it, ClipMate has a Binary display that will show you a binary dump of the data.  It's available in the trial version.  If you don't see the Binary tab in the display window, turn it on in the Tools | Options | Editor dialog.